# Fragment for Image Viewer (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-image

I'm trying to create a simple fragment that merely displays an image when clicked. I'm getting numerous errors inlcuding "the method findViewbyId(int) is undefined for the type ExampleFragment", "Inflater cannot be resolved", and  "imageview_main cannot be resolved or is not a field." imageview_main is a layout I have created, imageView1 is an image contained in that layout. Here is the fragment code:

```
package com.firstproject.simplemenu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

Button button;
ImageView image;


public ExampleFragment() {

}

public static ExampleFragment newInstance() {
    return new ExampleFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    return Inflater.inflate(R.layout.iamgeview_main, container, false);
    }

public void addListenerOnButton() {


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eagle);
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

findViewById is a method in the class Activity. To avoid passing an instance of the entire activity use a WeakRefence (see  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)
for example

```
private WeakReference<MainActivity> activity;

public ExampleFragment(MainActivity mainActivity) {
   activity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(mainActivity);
} 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)activity.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    return Inflater.inflate(R.layout.iamgeview_main, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Do I need to include some library? When I try this given code I get all sorts of errors on Inflater, activity, imageview_main and WeakReference...

Comment: could you post the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following modifications to your code ;

1) Import Fragment from support library(important if running on early versions of android);

2) Insted of Inflater I used the inflater received as method param;

3) I created a method findViewById that can be used in this fragment;

4) I moved some of the initialisation code in the method onActivityCreated ; [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

you cand find more about that method ;

```
package com.example.gctest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

Button button;
ImageView image;


public ExampleFragment() {

}

public static ExampleFragment newInstance() {
    return new ExampleFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); this will raise NullPointerException because the parent view has not been created. Is is created with this method;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.iamgeview_main, container, false); //just return the  view ;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //here you can initialise your variables,listeners,e.t.c ;
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

/**
 * You can use this method in order to access the child views of the fragment parent view;
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
protected View findViewById(int id)
{
    return getView().findViewById(id);
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eagle);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Great thank you! That took care of the errors in the fragment, but for some reason my main activity still isn't letting me call the fragment. I'm getting am error "The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments(int, ExampleFragment)" on the line: replace(R.id.container, ExampleFragment.newInstance())....any ideas?

Comment: 1)Make  sure that your activity extends FragmentActivity,2) your replace fragment code looks like this FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(containerResId, ExampleFragment.newInstance());
  
  fragmentTransaction.commit(); !Again import from support library import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;