# How can I pass an imageview to a method in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, share-intent

Basically when I try to pass an imageview or a view to a method in a fragment the result is null. The best I could until now was as code below that at least does not crash. I am inflating two fragments. What is wrong?

Layout has two xml files:

**fragment_image_slider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

...

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sharethis"
        android:clickable="true"
    ...
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**image_fullscreen_preview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

...

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**FRAGMENT CODE**

```
private ImageView deleteThis, shareThis;    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_slider, container, false);
           shareThis = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.sharethis);
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = 
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);
    final ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

      Image image = images.get(position);

        Glide
                .with(getActivity())
                .load(image.getPhotoUrl())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(imageViewPreview);

        shareThis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onShareItem(imageViewPreview);
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    public void onShareItem(ImageView v) {
    //ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_preview); if I use `View v` as parameter the app crashes
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(v); // return null
       ...
    }
```

How do I pass this variable to the `onShareItem` method?

Comment: We need to see the layout code and an initial recommendation will be to use onViewCreated to find views instead of onCreateView. OnViewCreated have the already inflated view as an argument, oberwrite by pressing ctrl+o

Answer (score 1):

You cant ge't image_preview in onViewCreated because it belong to the Activity and is not yet created.

Override onActivityCreated in the Fragment and there you have to find the ImageView in the Activity, the view you are using in onViewCreated is your fragment layout:

getActivity().findViewById...

Comment: Your mean do the same as here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417087/751630

Comment: Close, you can't use findViewById() directlt in a Fragment, you have to do it by accesing a view first and in thar view find what you need. Insise onActivityCreated use getActivity().findViewById();

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the layout code, I recommend you could use a callback.

Implement an interface in your activity class, where its method is the logic you wish to execute that's going to modify or consume your image view.  Then, instead of passing the imageview to your onShareItem you could pass 'this' and call the callback with any parameters you need.